# Heroku duplica archivos en la carpeta staticfiles cuando hago collectstatic

Tags: python, django, heroku

Tengo una aplicación Django corriendo en Heroku Dynos, básicamente, mi problema es que la carpeta *static* donde tengo los archivos estáticos se duplica y crea de nuevo los archivos en *staticfiles*, y además, hace que se dupliquen los archivos con versiones para caché.

Lo cual, provoca que donde tengo 240 MG de aplicación, se duplique a 420 MG cada vez que hago **python manage.py collectstatic.**

Este es mi archivo **settings.py** (Variables importantes), siguiendo las indicaciones de https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets

```
       ...
       BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
       PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

       ...

       MIDDLEWARE = [
       ...
       'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
       ]


        STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'staticfiles')
        MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
        MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
         STATICFILES_DIRS = (
            os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
         )


       STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
       STATIC_URL = '/static/'
       
       STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
       MEDIA_URL = '/media/'


       ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu configuración de STATICFILES_STORAGE es la responsable de que se dupliquen los archivos. Prueba comentarla y vuelve a probar usar collectstatic. Al comentarla usará los valores por defecto.

```
[
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora no me ha duplicado los archivos. Pero, ¿Habría alguna manera de que no me duplicase static en staticfiles?

Comment: Lo que hace whitenoise es que comprime y crea una nueva versión de los static cada vez que haces collectstatic agregandole un hash al final del nombre del nuevo archivo. Y no elimina los antiguos por eso los duplica. Sinceramente no conozco una forma de hacerlo con whitenose que no genere duplicados. Puedes usarlo sin whitenose sin problemas y cuando haya cambios en un static haces collectstatic y solo actualiza ese archivo.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.